# Read perl script from c++

Tags: c++, perl

I've to read and parse HTML file and populate a data structure (in C++). I'm planning to do the parsing using perl (so I can use some other perl modules.). My requirement is this.

1. Get the file from gui (C++ code)
2. Pass it to perl.
3. Parse file on perl side (*perl script* using some other perl modules), populate the C++ structure
4. Continue working on C++ side with the populated structure.

I'm reading about extending and embedding perl, but unable to figure out the correct procedure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick fix: have the Perl script output a simplified text format, read that through a pipe on the C++ side, build the structure.

Comment: This, I've thought of and decided against it. A system call to perl, and parsing on C++-side. The data structure (class) may contain pointers to other classes. so I want to avoid this.

Comment: have you tried serializing the data using Data::Dumper for example. You are going to have a real hard time passing Perl objects out to a C++ program intact.

Comment: I'd do what @larsmans suggests.  Parse it in a separate Perl program, output it in some format C++ can understand (JSON, YAML, XML...) and let C++ turn that into a struct.  Embedding Perl is fraught with peril and you won't be able to move Perl classes and objects easily into C++ structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your reading did you find [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) in Perl's documentation?  That's the definitive resource for learning how to embed Perl in a C/C++ program.  The author of the document was one of the original mod_perl developers, I believe.

I don't think that embedding Perl for a trivial task would be the easiest solution when compared to doing a system call to perl and parsing the result, but for more involved needs it's certainly a solution.

Comment: You don't even have to do much parsing if you use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) to return bytes that can be slopped straight into a `struct`.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [swig](http://www.swig.org/) to connect C++ and Python. The documentation says it works for Perl, also.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative is to have perl drive your C++ code. Write a function that has a perl-side implementation that calls a corresponding C-side implementation. Do man perlxs and perlxstut for more info.

Edit: Or read it online at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html.